# Cannot access mongoDB after "meteor deploy myapp.com"

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment

I deployed my app using `meteor deploy myapp.com`, and directed my DNS to `myapp.meteor.com`.

The app is now available at myapp.com, and I have no problem running it. It's the correct version that was deployed to "myapp.com" and not the older "myapp.meteor.com" version.

But I cannot access mongodb for this deployed version.

When I run `meteor mongo myapp.com`, I get this at the terminal:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: sg-mother1-6242.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_com
2016-03-10T16:46:18.659-0800 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

I am also getting the same error when I run `meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com`:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: someserver.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_meteor_com
2016-03-10T16:45:54.367-0800 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

When I do `meteor mongo --url myapp.com`, I do get a URL back of the form:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<some-servername>.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_com
```

But I cannot connect to this URL using Robomongo. I get an error:

```
Cannot connect to MongoDB (<some-servername>.servers.mongodirector.com:27017),
error: Unable to connect to MongoDB
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I connect to the mongoDB for the app I deployed on my custom domain? Preferably using some GUI tool such as Robomongo?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, is that the local install of Meteor uses Mongodb 2.6 and newly deployed Meteor sites use Mongodb 3.0

When you call `meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com` you are using meteor's locally installed version of mongo (version 2.6) but you are trying to access the deployed mongodb (version 3.0). This results in the authentication error you are getting.

[This link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-mongo-xxx-meteor-com-giving-exception-login-failed-workaround/15289) describes a workaround that worked for me. I had to tweak it a little, but this is what I did:

1. [Install or update](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/install-community/) your local version of Mongo (not through Meteor).
2. Run the command `meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com` to get the MONGO_URL. As you already mentioned, you'll get something like

   ```
   mongodb://<user>:<password>@<some-servername>.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_com
   ```
3. Connect to the MONGO_URL using your updated non-meteor version of mongo by running

   ```
   mongo mongodb://<user>:<password>@<some-servername>.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_com
   ```
4. You should now be in the mongoshell, connected to your deployed mongodb. You should see something like this `RS-mother1-0:PRIMARY>`  in your mongo shell. You still need to switch to your app's DB though. So call `use myapp_com` from the shell.

You should now be able to view collections and run mongo commands on your deployed meteor mongodb.

I'm not sure why you can't connect to Robomongo using the username and password meteor generates for you in the MONGO_URL. I suspect it's because it might expire. If you still want to connect using Robomongo, I'd recommend creating a user on the database now that you are logged in. And then later on, using that user to log into Robomongo.

- Creating the user in the mongo shell:

  ```
  db.createUser({ "user" : "my_user", "pwd": "my_password", "roles" : ["readWrite"]})
  ```
- New MONGO_URL:

  ```
  mongodb://my_user:my_password@<some-servername>.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/myapp_com
  ```